# Javascript - Returned item after AJAX is always undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, return

I have this function :

```
function get_non_authorized_bulk_edit_option_values() {
        var modificable_column_names = get_write_user_values();
        alert(modificable_column_names);
}
```

It is calling this one (I didn't paste all the details such as xml variable content or OnError function) :

```
function get_write_user_values() {
    var request = $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            async: false,
                            url: "model/_get_user_groups_info_pipe.php",
                            data: xml,
                            contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: OnSuccess,
                            error: OnError
    });


    function OnSuccess(data,status,request) {
        var modificable_column_names = [];

        $.each(data.column_name, function(index, value) {
            modificable_column_names.push(value);
        });

        alert(modificable_column_names);

        return modificable_column_names;
    }
}
```

When I alert the modificable_column_names array, it's working in the get_write_user_values() function but not in get_non_authorized_bulk_edit_option_values() function (I get undefined). 
I tried with object or string instead of a table but I have the same problem. 
Why isn't it working?

PS: I have a synchronous call there because I absolutely need the result of this function before continuing (I know it's not the best option).

Comment: Never ever use `async: false`. It is a terrible practice and is deprecated. Look at warning thrown in browser console. There is never any need to use it.

Comment: @Max please check my edited answer

Comment: You get `undefined` because `get_write_user_values` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually returning anything from the get_write_user_values() functions.  This function simply starts the ajax call and returns immediately, returning undefined even before the ajax call has completed.  At some stage your onSuccess function will be called with the data, but by that stage, your get_non_authorized_bulk_edit_option_values() function has run and processed the undefined value.  You need to make use of the promise api jquery ajax provides.

```
function get_write_user_values() {
    var promise = $.ajax({ ... }) // remove the success and error handlers 
    .then(onSuccess, onError)

    function onSuccess(data) {
       // do stuff to the data
       return processed_data;
    }
    function onError(err) {
        console.log('An error with the api');
        return err;
    }

    return promise;
 }

function get_non_authorized_bulk_edit_option_values() {
   get_write_user_values()
   .then (function (processed_data) {
        alert(processed_data);
    });
}
```

This will ensure that the code in get_non_authorized_bulk_edit_option_values will wait for the data from the ajax call to arrive before executing its alert.

Read up on https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/ if you are not familiar with jquery promises.

Comment: Thanks. I tried but I get : "Uncaught ReferenceError: onSuccess is not defined" even if I have the onSuccess function just right after (and the success and error handlers are removed from the ajax declaration).

Comment: Check the capitalization of your function names, I noticed yours was OnSucces, capital O, mine was lower case.  ALso small ninja edit to return the promise, which is vital :)

Comment: Yes, I was wondering where it was going. Perfect, now it is working! Thanks a lot.